# Sending integer with intent (android studio)

Tags: android, android-intent

ANSWERED

I am trying to send and int to another activity.There is a button in first act. and it opens second act. and takes int from here to other page.But i cant start two of them at one time.
Here is my first activity :

```
public class ana_ekran extends AppCompatActivity {

    public TextView ana_ekran_kule;
    public TextView ana_ekran_can;
    public  int ana_ekran_can_int=30;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ana_ekran);



    ana_ekran_kule=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    ana_ekran_can=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    ana_ekran_can.setText(ana_ekran_can_int+" CAN");

    }
public void devam (View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),fight_1.class);
    i.putExtra("deger",  ana_ekran_can_int);
    startActivity(i);
    startActivity(new Intent(this,fight_1.class));

}
}
```

and this is second:

```
public class fight_1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    public TextView fight_1_can;
    public int fight_1_can_int;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fight_1);

        fight_1_can=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        int i = getIntent().getIntExtra("deger",-1);
        fight_1_can_int=i;
        fight_1_can.setText(fight_1_can_int+"");

    }

}
```

Comment: remove this ` startActivity(new Intent(this,fight_1.class));` why redundant?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `startActivity(i);` will do the same thing as next line but it will carry the data as well whereas `startActivity(new Intent(this,fight_1.class));` will only start the other instance of `fight_1` activity so

```
public void devam (View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),fight_1.class);
    i.putExtra("deger", ana_ekran_can_int);
    startActivity(i);
    // start fight_1 again without any data so not required
    //startActivity(new Intent(this,fight_1.class));    
}
```

Comment: Okay, can you tell me about how can i send an integer to another page?

Comment: @AlperGöktepe you are already doing it using `i.putExtra("deger", ana_ekran_can_int);` so in `fight_1` inside oncreate or later methods  do `int i = getIntent().getIntExtra("deger",-1);`

Comment: OK but it doesnt take the number from first page, herte is my code:                                                            
   public TextView ana_ekran_can;
    public  int ana_ekran_can_int=30;

Comment: next:  and     ana_ekran_can=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    ana_ekran_can.setText(ana_ekran_can_int+" CAN");                                     this is the second act.          fight_1_can=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        fight_1_can.setText(fight_1_can_int+"");

        int I = getIntent().getIntExtra("deger",-1);
        fight_1_can_int=I;

Comment: move this line `fight_1_can.setText(fight_1_can_int+"");` after `fight_1_can_int=I;`

Comment: it helped but now it makes the number -1, i cant understand the problem

Comment: Kindly edit your question and post the updated code of both activities ,related to this issue

Comment: I told you to remove `startActivity(new Intent(this,fight_1.class));`

Comment: Oh my god im so sorry, thanks for your patient and helps.Good evening!

Comment: I am glad that I could help, happy coding